# Manually control hdmi output of a Beaglebone/Raspberry

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, hdmi, beagleboneblack

I need to drive a led matrix which acts as a monitor. therefore i want to connect it to my beaglebone, which of course runs on a headless debian.

My first thought was to install some gui like lxde, to see if there is any output at all.

but the real question is if i could simply control the hdmi "directly", which means that i want to maybe give the driver or whatever is responsible for driving the hdmi output a picture or video signal which then should appear on the connected monitor. i couldn't find anything on that topic on google because the search term "hdmi" delivers only Home Theater like problems, which doesn't help me.

is there a possibility to achieve the above mentioned? is it possible to "control" the hdmi via command line? which driver or module or whatever is driving the hdmi output on a beaglebone?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the TI AM335x series as used in the beaglebone only has a parallel display output, so there probably is some hdmi converter chip on the board. The registers for display configuration are well documented in the [reference manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spruh73). There are also additional documents like application notes to help you.

But I don't understand why you need this. If your LED matrix has an hdmi input, you should be able to drive it like any other hdmi display. If it doesn't (give us more information!), hdmi is probably not the interface you want to use to drive it. In this case, tell us about that LED matrix and we'll find out whether your project is on topic here.